Cryptojovi.com is asking me to deposit funds before I can withdraw
So someone messaged me and asked if I could help them withdraw there funds because it’s illegal in there country and they’re not allowed to so they sent the bitcoin to me on cryptojovi.com and now when I try to withdraw support says I need to deposit atleast 250-300 to my account to be able to withdraw my full balance to save from scammers and money laundering. Does this seem legit.
